# authenticate request manually in Filter with SecurityContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I am trying to implement spring security with authentication in spring boot ,i have a filter in which i am trying to authenticate request manually ,note that i do not want to use requestMatcher to permit request,this is my customFilter

```
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper mapper;

private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
public AuthTokenFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.authenticationManager= authenticationManager;
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("Amit47@Gmail.com","ABC@!@#");
    SecurityContext sc= SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    sc.setAuthentication(authentication);
}}
```

but i am encountering following issue while a request is made from postman

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.isEqualsMethod(AopUtils.java:151) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:175) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy119.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:216) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy119.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:216) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy119.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Please find Below SecurityConfig FilterChain Bean

```
 @Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public DefaultSecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http

            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint())
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(authTokenFilter(http), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
}


@Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder =
                http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);;
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }
```

Comment: we have no idea what is going on. this is impossible to answer, you must include all annotations above the class, your security configuration and your FULL trace logs. This is WAY too little information. Voted to close